# SFMC Backup data view into DE: error Cannot insert a NULL value into a non-nullable

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, data-views

I'm trying to backup the data views, using automation. As they get deleted once in 6 months, and we need the data.
I have following the files and PK according to the documentation: [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=0)

But I keep get the same error for all DEs:

```
Cannot insert a NULL value into a non-nullable column.
View Activity Details
```

Setup:

1. destination DE PK are set to all non NULLABLE fields from documentation
2. destination DE Fileds names are copied from documentation
3. Automation is overwriting destination DE (at the moment, later will update)

Here is an example for the _Open destination DE set up:
[Open DE destination](https://prnt.sc/t1cruk)

SQL query:

```
select *
from _Open
```

Should be very simple, what am I missing?
Do I need to change PK?

Here is the data we need:

- Sent
- Click
- Open
- Bounce
- Undeliverable SMS

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot the issue is with your PK fields, TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID and TriggeredSendcustomerkey only have values when the send is from a triggeredsend

For _Open your Pk *could* be jobid/listid/batchid/subid/eventdate

Comment: Thanks. I really don't understand then why it's not nullable in MD documents.